# How to add a Decoder & Attention Layer to Bidirectional Encoder with tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, attention-mechanism, gru, encoder

I am a beginner in machine learning and I'm trying to create a spelling correction model that spell checks for a small amount of vocab (approximately 1000 phrases). Currently, I am refering to the tensorflow 2.0 tutorials for 1. NMT with Attention, and 2. Text Generation. I have completed up to an encoding layer but currently I am having some issue matching up the shape of the following layers (decoder and attention) with the previous (encoder). The encoder in the tutorial is not bidirectional whereas I am trying to implement a bidirectional encoder. Below is my code for the encoder and attention layer.

```
class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, enc_units, batch_sz):
    super(Encoder, self).__init__()
    self.batch_sz = batch_sz
    self.enc_units = enc_units
    self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
    self.bigru = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(
        tf.keras.layers.GRU(self.enc_units, 
                            return_sequences=True, 
                            return_state=True, 
                            recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                            dropout=0.2,
                            recurrent_dropout=0.2))

  def call(self, x, hidden):
    x = self.embedding(x)
    output, forward_state, backward_state = self.bigru(x, initial_state = hidden)
    hidden_state = tf.convert_to_tensor([forward_state, backward_state])
    return output, hidden_state

  def initialize_hidden_state(self):
      init_state = [tf.zeros((self.batch_sz, self.enc_units)) for i in range(2)]
      return init_state

embedding_dim = 10
enc_units = 100
batch_size = 64
encoder = Encoder(vocab_size, embedding_dim, enc_units, batch_size)

# sample input
sample_hidden = encoder.initialize_hidden_state()
sample_output, sample_hidden = encoder(example_input_batch, sample_hidden)
print ('Encoder output shape: (batch size, sequence length, units) {}'.format(sample_output.shape))
print ('Encoder Hidden state shape: (batch size, units) {}'.format(sample_hidden.shape))
```

> WARNING:tensorflow:Layer gru_20 will not use cuDNN kernel since it doesn't meet the cuDNN kernel criteria. It will use generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:Layer gru_20 will not use cuDNN kernel since it doesn't meet the cuDNN kernel criteria. It will use generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:Layer gru_20 will not use cuDNN kernel since it doesn't meet the cuDNN kernel criteria. It will use generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU
>
> Encoder output shape: (batch size, sequence length, units) (64, 27, 200)
>
> Encoder Hidden state shape: (batch size, units) (2, 64, 100)
>
> Encoder Hidden (backward) state shape: (batch size, units) (64, 100)

```
class BahdanauAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, units):
    super(BahdanauAttention, self).__init__()
    self.W1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
    self.W2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
    self.V = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

  def call(self, query, values):
    # query hidden state shape == (batch_size, hidden size)
    # query_with_time_axis shape == (batch_size, 1, hidden size)
    # values shape == (batch_size, max_len, hidden size)
    # we are doing this to broadcast addition along the time axis to calculate the score
    query_with_time_axis = tf.expand_dims(query, 1)

    # score shape == (batch_size, max_length, 1)
    # we get 1 at the last axis because we are applying score to self.V
    # the shape of the tensor before applying self.V is (batch_size, max_length, units)
    score = self.V(tf.nn.tanh(
        self.W1(query_with_time_axis) + self.W2(values)))

    # attention_weights shape == (batch_size, max_length, 1)
    attention_weights = tf.nn.softmax(score, axis=1)

    # context_vector shape after sum == (batch_size, hidden_size)
    context_vector = attention_weights * values
    context_vector = tf.reduce_sum(context_vector, axis=1)

    return context_vector, attention_weights

attention_layer = BahdanauAttention(10)
attention_result, attention_weights = attention_layer(sample_hidden, sample_output)

print("Attention result shape: (batch size, units) {}".format(attention_result.shape))
print("Attention weights shape: (batch_size, sequence_length, 1) {}".format(attention_weights.shape))
```

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      1 attention_layer = BahdanauAttention(10)
----> 2 attention_result, attention_weights = attention_layer(sample_hidden, sample_output)
      3 
      4 print("Attention result shape: (batch size, units) {}".format(attention_result.shape))
      5 print("Attention weights shape: (batch_size, sequence_length, 1) {}".format(attention_weights.shape))

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [2,1,64,10] vs. [64,27,10] [Op:AddV2]

Answer (score 0):

In that tutorial, they created a new `BahdanauAttention()` class that is supposed to be inserted into the `Decoder()` object. Attention is something the Decoder uses, not the Encoder. The model as it is isn't complete. Add a Decoder and change its input shape to make it work.

However, let me conclude with some thoughts on this implementation:

I don't think you need bidirectionality when you use Attention mechanisms. The goal of attention is to allow for a useful signal that is far away back in time to travel to the output quicker (without having to pass through all the RNN cells and get lost mid way). For that reason, before the rise of Attention mechanisms, Bidirectional RNN layers used to be the best tool to achieve this higher "fully-connectedness" of Seq2seq Networks. But now that you have attention, you don't need that anymore since you have a tool that does that in a more flexible and powerful way.

By adding bidirectionality, you are forcing the model to distribute its attention on a duplicate trend, the Decoder would receive two copies of the same signal (left-to-right and right-to-left) but with one attention to distribute on all. I think this is counterintuitive and undesirable, the very concept of Attention is messed up. I suggest you to drop bidirectionality and use just plain Attention. It would be interesting to compare its performance against a model with bidirectionality and no attention (I'm pretty sure attentional models would win hands down).

-.-.-.-.-.-

PS: Since tensorflow 2.1, the class `BahdanauAttention()` is now packed into a keras layer called `AdditiveAttention()`, that you can call as any other layer, and stick it into the `Decoder()` class. There is also another keras layer simply called `Attention()` that implements Luong Attention; it might be interesting to compare their performance.